# Some images don't appear on image view control xamarin.ios

Tags: xamarin.ios

I enrolled some `images` into assets folder and work fine in image view but when add new `images` to the assets folder they were added correctly but not appeared when i choose an image to be set into `UIImageView` and there are about `6` `images` only appears on image view control and the whole remaining images can't be appeared, i tried much time to clean and build the solution but that's useless.

Comment: In the configuration, check if the "build action" is "BundleResource" or "content"

Comment: Configuration of what?, the whole solution?, note that i am working with xamarin.ios project.

Comment: in your hierarchy project, go to Resources, and select your image, right click and properties, you will see the Build section, who contains the "Build Action", i have this option just picking the image in the rigth of my screen

Comment: @AyaSaber Try to post some code or provide a blank sample just throwing this issues.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This problem was caused as there were cached images on Mac, so the solution is o removed these cached items and add the images again into the assets folder, Thanks all.